# How can a mongodb query run with variable substitution

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this document in Mongo

```
{
    "_id" : "hxQee6xCQSD9C9Qok",
    "bank_account" : {
        "12345" : {
            "account" : "12345",
            "type" : "bank_account"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run a query against mongoDB, I know I can do this

`db.donate.find({'bank_account.12345.account': '12345'})`

But what I would like to do is use a variable to search for the account number, '12345'
So I've tried this

```
var bankNumber = '12345';
var accountLookup = {bank_account[bankNumber]account: bankNumber};
var obj = db.donate.findOne(accountLookup);
```

and I get this error

`Error: Line 2: Unexpected token [`

If I wrap this in quotes it doesn't work either. How can I format my query to lookup either by the object '12345' or by the account property '12345'?

Comment: "bank_account[bankNumber]account" is a syntax error, have you tried bank_account[bankNumber].account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assemble your query key programmatically:

```js
var bankNumber = '12345';
var accountLookup = {};
accountLookup['bank_account.' + bankNumber + '.account'] = bankNumber;
var obj = db.donate.findOne(accountLookup);
```